# Send value through ajax to php switch

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to send values from radio button to a php switch, but the switch doesn't pick up th ajax response. Here's my form:

```
       <form action="" id="demoForm" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Demo form</legend>
                <span style="font-size: 0.9em;">This ajax submit demo form.</span>
                <p>

                    <input class="myradio" type="radio" name="email" value="pop" />
                    <input class="myradio" type="radio" name="email"  value="gdp" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" style="float: right; clear: both; margin-right: 3px;" value="Submit" />
                </p>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Here's my js file:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); 

    email = $(".myradio:checked").val()

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'index.php',

        data: {
            "email" : email},

        dataType : 'json',  

        success : function(data){

            $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success').text(data).show(500);
            if (data.error === true)
                $('#demoForm').show(500);
        }

    });

    return false;
});
});
```

And here's my index.php with the switch:

```
<?php

$action =  htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['email']));



 switch ( $action ) {
 case 'pop':
 pop();
 break;
 case 'gdp':
 gdp();
 break;
 default:
 homepage();
 }

 function pop() {

 require("chore2.php");

 }


 function gdp() {


 }

function homepage() {


require("homepage.php");

 }

 ?>
```

In firebug I can se that the repsonse looks correct, ie: index.php?email=pop

But the switch dosn't pick up the value, and nothing happens. Anybody know why?

Comment: You can try and add the 'fail' method after 'success' to see if it reaches the PHP page. index.php?email=pop shouldn't be the response but more like the request.

Comment: put your switch code in a function and pass your $action to that function

Comment: Also, don't leave a trailing ',' after the success function IE8 and lower won't execute the script.

Comment: Look at Zalks newest answer. I believe your problem is that you are using a submit button to send the ajax call. But you're not stopping the form from being submitted to the ajax call isn't executing well. While it is executing, the form also gets submitted and the page refreshes.

Comment: I tried with the e.preventDefault(); (see edited code) but still no luck.

Comment: @ComputerArts I've tried to add a $('#message').text(str) to the sucess function and it actually prints the str on submit. So it seems the function is working.